# como confirgurar las credenciales de mi servidor remoto en Laravel para conectar una base de datos oracle

Tags: laravel, vpn

Holaaa, he trabajado en Laravel localmente, pero ahora necesito hacer consultas de una base de datos situada en un servidor, pero alguien me puede ayudar a colocar esa confirguración?

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado?, ¿Cuáles son tus avances?... ¿Cuáles son tus errores?. Debes dar un ejemplo de lo que haz logrado hasta ahora

Comment: Holaa, pues hasta ahora tengo el .env, la pregunta es en que parte del archvivo debo configurar las credenciales del servidor

Comment: Debes instalar este repo https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en Laravel, pero he logrado la conexión creando un archivo en mi carpeta /Config llamado DataBase.php con el siguiente código

```php
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'connections' => [
  'mysql' => [
              'driver' => 'mysql',
              'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
              'host' => '127.0.0.1',
              'port' => '3306',
              'database' => 'mitiendaBd',
              'username' => 'root',
              'password' => '',
              'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
              'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
              'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
              'prefix' => '',
              'prefix_indexes' => true,
              'strict' => true,
              'engine' => null,
              'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
              ]) : [],
          ],
],
```

Importo mi archivo DataBase.php en donde vaya a utilizar la conexión e instancio la clase connections y la conexión a la bd remota.

Espero sea de ayuda.